# Retrieving a subset of a JSON object stored in Dynamo

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

Is it currently possible to retrieve a subset of a json object stored in Dynamo? For example, I have an attribute named record of JSON type which is an array of JSON objects:

```
records:
[
    {"K1": "V1" },
    {"K2": "V2" },
    {"K3": "V3" },
    {"K4": "V4" }
]
```

I store them in the JSON format in Dynamo. I wanted to know if I can only retrieve key value pairs 1 to 2 and not the 3rd and 4th one? I am unsure if I can provide a specific filter expression to do this operation.

If it is possible, I would love to hear the methodology as to how it can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the DynamoDB data type of "records" attribute? Is it Map?

Comment: I was thinking of two types - one as a json string after serializing it with something like gson. The second option was to serialize it but store it as a list rather than a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no JSON data type in DynamoDB. If you mean the data is stored as DynamoDB data type **`MAP`**, then the below solution should work for you.

In short, the filter expression should be something like below:-

```
FilterExpression : 'records.K1 = :recordsK1Value and records.K2 = :recordsK2Value'
```

If you need to have only "records.K1" and "records.K2" in output, you can use project expression for that.

```
ProjectionExpression : 'records.K1, records.K2'
```

**Full code:-**

```
public List<String> queryMoviesAndFilterByMapAttribute() {

    List<String> moviesJsonList = new ArrayList<>();

    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);

    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Movies");

    QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();

    querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("yearkey = :yearval and title = :titleval")
            //.withProjectionExpression("records.K1, records.K2")
            .withFilterExpression("records.K1 = :recordsK1Value and records.K2 = :recordsK2Value").withValueMap(
                    new ValueMap().withNumber(":yearval", 1991).withString(":titleval", "Movie with map attribute")
                            .withString(":recordsK1Value", "V1").withString(":recordsK2Value", "V2"));

    IteratorSupport<Item, QueryOutcome> iterator = table.query(querySpec).iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item movieItem = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Movie data ====================>" + movieItem.toJSONPretty());
        moviesJsonList.add(movieItem.toJSON());
    }

    return moviesJsonList;

}
```

**Sample output with all fields (i.e. without project expression):-**

```
Movie data ====================>{
  "yearkey" : 1991,
  "records" : {
    "K1" : "V1",
    "K2" : "V2",
    "K3" : "V3",
    "K4" : "V4"
  },
  "title" : "Movie with map attribute"
}
```

**Sample output after un-commenting the project expression:-**

Please note that other fields such as yearkey, title, K3 and K4 are not present in the output.

```
Movie data ====================>{
  "records" : {
    "K1" : "V1",
    "K2" : "V2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. This really helps. I had one question though. This implementation is for a Map. Is it possible to retrieve a subset of a List of a similar fashion? I am guessing the concept of having the keys in the projectionExpression will differ? I want to know only if its possible, wouldn't want you to take the trouble of solving it completely. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible as long as it is a List of String values. Example:- FilterExpression : 'contains (records, :recordsK1Value)',
ProjectionExpression : 'records[0], records[1]',

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the help!